# List of tables along with key information - Oracle

Tags: oracle

I am trying to fetch the list of tables, column information including the data type from the Oracle metadata tables. You can see the list of columns below. Somehow primary key and foreign key constraint data that I am pulling seems to be replicating for all the columns of that table in question, whereas I expect null for the columns which are not tagged as primary key or foreign key in the constraint tables. 
I have used a left outer join, but seems like it is not working as expected due to the joining conditions. Any help would be appreciated.

```
SELECT AO.OWNER, 
AO.OBJECT_NAME, 
ATC.COLUMN_NAME, 
ATC.DATA_TYPE, 
ATC.NULLABLE,
AC.CONSTRAINT_NAME
FROM ALL_OBJECTS AO
JOIN
ALL_TAB_COLUMNS ATC
ON AO.OBJECT_NAME=ATC.TABLE_NAME
LEFT  JOIN
ALL_CONS_COLUMNS ACC
ON 
--ACC.column_name=ATC.column_name and
ACC.TABLE_NAME=ATC.TABLE_NAME
inner JOIN
ALL_CONSTRAINTS AC
    ON 
     AC.TABLE_NAME=ACC.TABLE_NAME
     AND
     AC.CONSTRAINT_NAME=ACC.CONSTRAINT_NAME
     --and atc.table_name=ac.table_name
WHERE AO.OBJECT_TYPE = 'TABLE'
 AND AO.OWNER = 'XYZ'
 AND AO.OBJECT_NAME='ABC'
AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE IN ('P','R')
ORDER BY AO.OBJECT_NAME, ATC.COLUMN_NAME
```

Comment: Can you edit your question, and include the output of at least some of rows that your query produced, enough for us to see what is replicating.

Comment: Your joins don't include `owner` in their conditions; do you have the same tables/constraints in multiple schemas? And why have you commented out the column name condition?

Comment: Alex, the owner I didn't feel important because I don't have the same tables/constraints in multiple schema. Also column_name condition seemed to only return the column/table data against the primary key and the foreign key almost as if it was an inner join (whereas it is a left outer join), so I tried removing that condition to check further

Answer (score 0):

I think your join conditions are not proper and `owner` must be used in join conditions as `all_` views are uses

You should try following query:

```
SELECT AT.OWNER, 
AT.TABLE_NAME, 
LISTAGG(ATC.COLUMN_NAME,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ATC.COLUMN_ID) AS  COLUMN_NAMES,
LISTAGG(ATC.DATA_TYPE,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ATC.COLUMN_ID) AS  DATA_TYPE, 
LISTAGG(ATC.NULLABLE,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ATC.COLUMN_ID) AS  NULLABLE,
AC.CONSTRAINT_NAME
FROM ALL_TABLES AT
JOIN
ALL_TAB_COLUMNS ATC
ON AT.TABLE_NAME=ATC.TABLE_NAME
AND AT.OWNER = ATC.OWNER
LEFT JOIN
ALL_CONS_COLUMNS ACC
ON ATC.COLUMN_NAME = ACC.COLUMN_NAME
AND ACC.TABLE_NAME = AT.TABLE_NAME
AND AC.OWNER = ACC.OWNER
LEFT JOIN ALL_CONSTRAINTS AC
ON AT.TABLE_NAME = AC.TABLE_NAME
AND AC.CONSTRAINT_NAME = ACC.CONSTRAINT_NAME
AND AT.OWNER = AC.OWNER
WHERE AT.OBJECT_TYPE = 'TABLE'
 AND AT.OWNER = 'XYZ'
 AND AT.OBJECT_NAME='ABC'
AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE IN ('P','R')
GROUP BY AT.OWNER, 
AT.TABLE_NAME, 
AC.CONSTRAINT_NAME
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to execute this. seems like there is some syntax error in your query. Will get there :)